# Design/Split hanging in Webform

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Until about an hour or so ago, I had no problems with Visual Studio - I could view my webforms, make changes etc.  All of a sudden, clicking Design or Split just hangs.  I don't get an error, it just sits there.  I can close the form, but going back into Design view for any for webform does the same thing.

I created a new blank web project, added a blank Default.aspx page - same issue.

I have tried restarting the computer, creating a new windows user and trying on that account and installing AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909 (which was an update that was showing up in Visual Studio).

Nothing is working, anyone know of any tips that might get it working?

EDIT:

If I close the webform and right click it in Solution Explorer and view markup and then click Shift-F7 to get design view, I get the following error:

Class not registered looking for object with clsid {A53914B4-1C62-4D60-8E8D-C7B67B4DFF87}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling for a long time and trying lots of different approaches, the only successful approach was running the Visual Studio installer and selecting Repair.

This took the better part of an hour to run, but has corrected the issue.

For what it is worth - the issue: Class not registered looking for object with clsid {A53914B4-1C62-4D60-8E8D-C7B67B4DFF87}

Seems to point to an error in the fpeditax.dll in the Common7\Packages folder

So final solution: Run a Repair from the installer.

Comment: I can't find an repair option. I am looking in Windows 7 control panel->Programs and Features

Comment: @kirsteng - I got to mine by using the original installer, not through Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Do two things:

1) right click the file you want to edit, and select "Open With" - make a note of which editor is the default, you'll need that later. Now, choose a different editor, and set that as default.

2) If (1) works, it's the editor that is jamming up, and you should do this: 
Start visual studio from a command line with this line:

```
devenv.exe /ResetUserData
```

you may want to delete the ".vs" folder in your project at the same time.

Now, do the same thing, right click the file, set BACK the default editor you took a note of, and you should be OK. This usually solves most of the issues related to a specific file type not wanting to work

Comment: I can open the file with the default as long as I open it in markup.  Tried your suggestion here - no luck