# ReInstall Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uninstallation, reinstall

My Win 10 version of Visual Studio 2015 Community edition failed to load with error "cannot find one or more components .Please reinstall the application".

I've tried repairing it but received nondescript errors so cancelled the repair (which also reported similar errors and eventually that 116 out 120 components had been repaired - iirc).

I then tried an uninstall, but that crashed windows.

On reboot, the VS 2015 uninstall options screen was displayed. Tried uninstall again but progress bar wasn't moving. Successfully cancelled it.

How do I get a working copy of VS 2015 running again (without breaking anything else on my machine)? Can I reinstall a new copy over the top of the old one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Before you perform the reinstall, you need to completely uninstall the VS community 2015 and provides 2 uninstall methods as below:

1. Forcibly uninstall command to remove:

•   Run the command executable file /uninstall /force like vs_community.exe /uninstall /force in the elevated command prompt. What’s more, you can see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/).

•   Reboot the computer

•   Rename or delete folders-

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

C:\users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015

C:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0

•   Go to the registry editor (start >> run >> regedit) and remove/rename the following registries-

a.  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

b.  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

c.  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

d.  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config

2. The Visual Studio Uninstaller tool: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases.

Before the next installation, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software and clean up the %temp% folder, use a healthy ISO file of VS community 2015 with update 3 to install, run the installer as administrator.

Comment: VS 2015 Community installed ok (from website rather than iso) except for 3 features: 2 versions of C++ (x64 and x86) redistributables were already present.

Also, ASP.net web tools 2015.1 (Beta 8) VS 2015 Package failed.

When I run VS 2015, I can load an existing console project but not a web site. Errors says web dev tools option must be installed. I can do this by repairing VS 2015 ensuring 'web dev tools' are checked in optional components.

Would you recommend this repair option (I don't recall seeing the components option during my initial attempt at repair)?

Comment: I guess the existing C++ versions are ok, as they would have been there on the previous version.

Edit: There seems to be an option to install "Web Dev Tools" (including ASP.net) in the "modify" option in control panel->apps & features->vs 2015->modify. Should I use this instead of "repair"?

Thanks.

Comment: Ps. I used option 2 the VS Unistaller tool.

Comment: @Gammerz, the option 'Microsoft Office Developer Tools' is the custom component and if you want to install it, you need to choose 'Modify' and check this option to update, we can know it from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx. For the error message about Visual C++ redistributable versions, you can ignore this error message, there should have the higher versions about it, so when VS want to install a lower version and it failed, you can check this under Control Panel-Programs and Features.

Comment: @ Sara On my first install of VS 2015, the Web Dev Tools were installed with the default install option. However, due to the error on the re-install, it appears that I have to install it as a custom option. This appeared to work,  as I can now create web forms, however, the web form designer hangs when I select the design or split options. :(

Comment: p.s. Shift-F7 on a web page produces error: Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID: { }
Repairing didn't fix this.

Comment: @Gammerz, how did you try to repair? Refer to the error message, I found some other community members solved this issue by repair VS through the VS installer(ISO) not under Control Panel-Programs and Features, you can check this similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728353/design-split-hanging-in-webform, you can download the ISO file of VS community 2015 with update 3 from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Comment: @Gammerz, BTW, did you added any controls into the designer? If so, you can create a new project and directly test this issue. If this issue persists, try to open an administrative CMD window and navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and run the commands: devenv /resetuserdata, devenv /safemode to troubleshot. Or delete or rename the folders: C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0.

Comment: I did not install from ISO file because my first download (which initially worked) was not from the ISO file. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Sarah thanks: The repair and dev tool install was from settings->system->apps.
Couldn't add any controls to designer because designer doesn't work (on new or existing project).
Problem remains in safe mode. Renaming directories prevented web page from displaying, so I don't really want to resetuserdata as I don't know how to undo if it causes a problem. 
Stackoverflow accepted answer says repair from installer, which I've done.

Comment: The ISO file is more stable for installation and repair, and you can have a try with download it and run it as administrator, then choose repair it. The /resetuserdata is to reset the old user data in VS, which should no affect your projects, you can backup your solutions/project before it.