# How do I repair VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728353/design-split-hanging-in-webform) and want to run Repair.
In WIndows 7, in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features,
when I double click on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 the only option is to uninstall.

I have the Professional edition

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37492.modify-repair-and-uninstall-visual-studio-2017-using-visual-studio-installer.aspx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch the Visual Studio Installer app from the Start menu. You will find the button to modify or uninstall from there.

Comment: It is not in the Visual Studio Group on the start menu, however it does appear when I type Visual Studio Installer into search.  The Reinstall option is hidden when I first open the installer but it does appear when I click "More"

Answer (score 1):

- goto this location, and tap on this executable file,
- C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe
- then select More, and then select Repair.