# "Unexpected token" within .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio

So yesterday I got a bluescreen, and since then my netFx is borked. I can't build, and VS finds lots of instances of this error:

[image: Screenshot]

Through the VS installer I uninstalled everything Framework and sdk related. Today I reinstalled all those things. Tried to compile, and still have these same errors.

Here's a copypaste form the build output:

```
0>C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(1,1): Error CS1056: Unexpected character ' 
1>C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(1,1): Error CS1056: Unexpected character ' 
4>C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(1,70): Error CS1056: Unexpected character '
6>C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(1,1): Error CS1056: Unexpected character ' 
2>C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(1,1): Error CS1056: Unexpected character ' 
3>C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(1,1): Error CS1056: Unexpected character ' 
5>C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(1,1): Error CS1056: Unexpected character '
```

I use VS2017. Tried VS2019 (Community) because why not, but it has the same problem.

Any idea what else I can try, before uninstalling and reinstalling everything related to visual studio and netFx?

Comment: Does this happen in every project you try to build?

Comment: Maybe you're missing one of those framework-or-sdk-related installables? Feel free to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744973/how-do-i-repair-vs2017

Comment: Actually it only happens in net451 projects - other versions dotnet core work.

Comment: Try to cleanup your `temp` folder and rebuild the project

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I did two things, but most probably deleting the temp files did the trick. Post that as an answer, then I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Squirrelkiller this is actually a duplicate with the question, which I've mentioned above